# Get average of hstore columns using activerecord + postgres

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, hstore

I have a set of quiz results stored in a hstore column as scores per topic. i.e.

```
Maths => 65
Physics => 70
English => 83
Music => 56
```

Is there a clean, idiomatic way (i.e. using Arel syntax) to calculate the average of each of these hstore groups? I'd like to find the average score in each topic for my students.

Answer (score 1):

You can [create a custom aggregate](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createaggregate.html) to average your hstore record structure for you. It's easy enough once you've worked through the example on the bottom of that page.

Longer term, you may find your life easier if you use relations to model structure when using a relational database.